# Call main thread on UICollectionView didSelectItemAt

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift3, grand-central-dispatch

I'm using a `UICollectionView` and a specific process runs when a user clicks on a cell. Since this process may take a few seconds, I want to show a view to the user with some processing message as soon as this process is about to start.

The general idea is as follows:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.someView.isHidden = false
        print("showing processing message is about to start")
    }

    // some process runs here which may take a few seconds to finish

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.someView.isHidden = true
        print("hidding processing message")
    }

}
```

For some unknown reason to me, those calls to main thread are performed just after `didSelectItemAt` has completely finished, thus that processing message disappears almost at the same time it appeared.

Does anybody know what I am missing here?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

What you described in your question seems normal based on the code snipped you have entered due to the fact `someView` is being called on the main thread.

If you would like `someView` to be hidden upon the process completing, it would be a better idea to hide `someView` in a completion closure of the processes you intend to run while `someView` is not hidden.